# why authentication fails with startTLS connection in apache directory studio?

Tags: ldap, openldap, apacheds

working environment: openldap on rocky linux 8.5 (vm)

problems:
I installed openldap on rocky linux vm, and issued self signed certificate with openssl.
(the installation guide i followed is [here](https://kifarunix.com/install-and-setup-openldap-on-rocky-linux-8/))

i tested startTLS connection on rocky linux with following command and it worked totally fine.

```
ldapsearch -x -w (password) -H ldap:/// -D cn=admin,dc=ldapmaster,dc=xxxxx,dc=com 
-b dc=ldapmaster,dc=xxxxx,dc=com -ZZ
```

but when i try to make a connection with Apache directory studio, it fails at authentication stage, with an error message below:

```
ERR_04169_RESPONSE_QUEUE_EMPTIED The response queue has been emptied, no response was found.
```

there was no problem with network parameter check.
I cant understand why my connection options works in rocky linux vm, not in ApacheDS.

any help would be highly aprreciated!

Comment: This is a DS M17 version problem with TLS 1.3, the workaround is to use M16.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It's a bug in the Java LDAP library that Apache Directory Studio uses.](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DIRSTUDIO-1287) Either wait for the next DirStudio release (I believe the problem is already fixed in Git/Svn) or **temporarily** disable TLSv1.3 support in your LDAP server.

---

(Note: Apache Directory Studio is not ApacheDS – that's an LDAP *server.*)