# Openldap: how to set and use TLS1.2

Tags: ldap, openldap

Is it possible to specify which TLS version to use in OpenLDAP 2.6.3?

We migrated to that new version of OpenLDAP, but now most LDAP clients do not want to work with it because it automatically establishes a connection with TLS1.3 (for example Apache Directory Studio has [an issue with TLS1.3 support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73689042/why-authentication-fails-with-starttls-connection-in-apache-directory-studio)).

We would be happy to use TLS1.3, but for now, the preferred version for us is 1.2